# General enrichment providing "uncurried" in scala

Tags: scala, currying, scalaz, shapeless

Does there exist a general enrichment for `f: A => B => ... => Z` in scala/scalaz/shapeless/etc. such that `f.uncurried:(A, B, ...) => Z`?

Currently I have this, but I believe there must be a pre-existing, more general solution somewhere.

```
implicit def enrichMyCurriedFunction[A, B, C] = new EnrichedCurriedFunction[A, B, C](_)

class EnrichedCurriedFunction[A, B, C](f: A => B => C) {
  def uncurried: (A, B) => C = (a, b) => f(a)(b)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There indeed is a builtin function:

```
val foo = (x: Int) => (y: Int) => x+y
foo: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>

Function.uncurried(foo)
res16: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```